# Ajax request using post

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using simple javascript to post a form via ajax.When i use get everything works well , but as it is get request all the parameters are visible.
With post this is my code but when i use it the request still uses get , any suggestions to fix it.

```
      var url = url;
      var params = params;



      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
      xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);


     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X_REQUESTED_WITH','XMLHttpRequest');  
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); 
     xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xmlhttp.open('POST', URL, true);` is the correct form. What is telling you that it's GET?

This is an AJAX request, that shows as post for me, so you can just grab that if you want: 
http://jsfiddle.net/robert/AUkt4/

Comment: in the net subtab of firebug I see it as GET.

Comment: When you go to that jsfiddle I posted, check the net tab for the URL I'm requesting, is that GET or POST?

Comment: the net panel gets deactivated in jsfiddle.

Comment: You should just be able to activate it again. Try using a webkit browser (Safari/Google Chrome) and use the developer tools and see if you see POST/GET.